# how to render a div on selection of radio button angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have a div in below with ngif, need to show it on selection of No in top div.. please help me on this

```
<div>
    <mat-radio-group>
    <mat-radio-button value="1" [(ngModel)]="options" [value]="true" [checked]="options"> No </mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="2"> Yes</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    </div>

<div *ngIf=checked>
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

Comment: <div>
<mat-radio-group>
<mat-radio-button value="1" [(ngModel)]="options" [value]="true" [checked]="options"> No </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2"> Yes</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</div>

<div *ngIf=checked>
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your ts file listen on the chang of the radio button

in your html file

```
<div>
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button (change)="onRadioChange($event)" value="1"> No </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2"> Yes</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</div>

<div *ngIf="canViewDiv">
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

in your .ts file

```
import { MdRadioChange } from '@angular/material';
....
canViewDiv: boolean = false;

....
onRadioChange(event: MdRadioChange) {
    this.canViewDiv = event.value == 1;
}
```

Comment: its not working yet, i think "event.value" is not evaluating, please help

Comment: Many Thanks Raed, i figured it out.. Salaam:) & Shukran

Comment: can u test it now?